# Drag, Javascript, removable listener with parameters

Tags: javascript, parameters, listener

sorry for the poor quality of the question (first js script, first post, no time but I would like to get a response for tomorow) here is a snippet to drag html elements. I had a "mousedown" listener to window, which get the element being clicked.
Then I attach to window a "mousemove" listener to drag the element over the page, and a second "mouseup" element to remove previous listeners.

I give you the full (unclean) code (dont read comments) but the problem is at the end of the function dragmod.

Can I, **without adding globals variables**, using Javascript and the addEventListener method, add listener who take arguments and removing it later?

Right now, I got an error when I try to remove the "mousemove" listener because handlerMove is not in the same scope.

Thanks for helping.

```
-- language: lang-js -->

    function moveTo(x, y, element) {
        //debugger;
        element.style.left = x + "px";
        /*element.style.paddingTop="";
        element.style.paddingLeft="";
        element.style.paddingBottom="";
        element.style.paddingRight="";*/
        element.style.top = y + "px";
    }

    function activeDrag() {
        window.addEventListener('mousedown', dragmod, true)
        return 'dragmod on'
    }

    function dragmod(event) {
        //debugger;
        console.log('mousedown')
        var element = document.elementFromPoint(event.clientX, event.clientY);
        if (element !== null) {
            element.style.position = 'absolute';
            //debugger;
            var elementRectangle = element.getBoundingClientRect();

            console.log("left pos.:", elementRectangle.left);
            console.log("top pos.:", elementRectangle.top);

            console.log("coord sourisx:",event.clientX);
            console.log("coord sourisy:", event.clientY);

            var offx = elementRectangle.left - event.clientX;
            var offy = elementRectangle.top - event.clientY;

            //console.log(element.style);

            //récuperation de l'élément le plus "en dessous"
            /*array=[];
        while (element!==null){
            console.log(element);
            element.style.display = "none";
            array.push(element);
            element = document.elementFromPoint(event.clientX, event.clientY);
        }

        for (element2 in array){
            element2.style.display = "inline";
        }

        element=array.peekBack();*/
            //console.log(element);
            window.handler={};// pour passer des parametre, faut fonction anonyme. Pour supprimer le listener par la suite, faut une référence. Donc on stock une fonction anonyme en globale


///////////////////////////////////////focus here///////////////////////////
            function handlerMove(e){
                listenMouseMove(e, element, offx, offy);
            }

            window.addEventListener('mousemove',handlerMove,true);

            function handlerUp(e){
                listenMouseUp(e, element);
            }

            window.addEventListener('mouseup', handlerUp,true);

        }
    }
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


    function listenMouseMove(event, element, offx, offy) {
        //debugger;
        console.log('mousemove')
        moveTo(event.clientX + offx, event.clientY + offy, element);
        event.stopPropagation();
        event.preventDefault();
    }

    function listenMouseUp(event, element) {
        //debugger;
        console.log('mouseup', element);
        window.removeEventListener('mousemove', handlerMove,true);
        window.removeEventListener('mouseup', handlerUp,true);
    }

    function closeDragmod() {
        window.removeEventListener('mousedown', dragmod);
        return 'dragmod off';
    }
```